# Некорректно обрабатывается переход назад

Tags: c#, события, windows-phone-8.1

По нажатию телефонной кнопки назад на титульной странице моего приложения, это событие не всегда корректно обрабатывается. Иногда как и должно быть выходит на рабочий стол, а иногда перегружает снова и снова мою титульную страницу.

```
public TitlePage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    // подключение обработчика для кнопки Назад
    HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed_onTitlePage;
}

private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed_onTitlePage(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    if (frame == null)
    {
         return;
    }

    if (frame.CanGoBack)
    {
        frame.GoBack();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я прописывал это для каждой страницы. Лучше сделать это в **App.xaml.cs** один раз, тогда кнопка **Back** обрабатывается корректно:

```
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += this.OnSuspending;

#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
    HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
#endif
}

#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    if (rootFrame != null && rootFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        rootFrame.GoBack();
    }
}
#endif
```